# Odoo.sh : Issue to create new module structure in Production stage

Tags: module, git-merge, odoo-13, scaffold, odoo.sh

Im trying to create a new module structure using the scaffold command in src/odoo/addons of the Production stage via odoo.sh's the editor.

**~/src/odoo/addons$ odoo-bin scaffold mymodule**

But I got the error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo-bin", line 8, in <module>

     odoo.cli.main()

   File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/cli/command.py", line 60, in main

     o.run(args)

   File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/cli/scaffold.py", line 39, in run

    {'name': args.name})

   File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/cli/scaffold.py", line 121, in render_to

    os.makedirs(destdir)

   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs

    mkdir(name, mode)

   OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/mymodule'
```

If creating the module structure in another stages, I can create it normally.

Am I not permission to create modules in the production stage, or the production stage is just used for merge with other stages?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does the /home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/mymodule directory has write permission?